# Load / Save data via hands on table

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, handsontable

I have a very simple variable:

```
var data2 = [
  [1234, 97, 2],
  [5678, 92, 2]
];
```

I want to get the load / save / autosave feature working on my 'hands on table' spreadsheet.

*The final spreadsheet will at most have  5 columns and around 500 rows.*

I can read javascript but I have never done server-side stuff before. I just want the simplest way to get the data loading and saving.

python anyone? node.js is cool too... :-)

This is the javascript component I am getting up and running: [hands on table](http://handsontable.com)

Comment: [node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love python as a language, but if you want simple, then go with what you know.

Comment: V happy to go along with node.js  @NightShadeQueen !  Quickest path to load / save functionality? any ideas how to do it :-) lol.